# Angularjs ng-options issue with Chrome browser only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-directive

I've spent last day trying to figure out why ng-options (Angularjs) not working properly in Chrome browser. I cross tested the code and only Chrome causing the problems.
When I choose some of the drop-down options the value in "selected item" doesn't get refreshed, especially for values (7,8,18,22) but it's inconsistent.

Here you have plunker:
   http://plnkr.co/edit/6wG2fBos7srhUdJZFFpL?p=preview

```
angular
```

In plnkr.co it works fine but try copy the code and run in Chrome you will see what I am talking about.
I've found some post with similar problems (key-selecting etc.). Is there any way around this problem please?

Comment: can you put the print screen for your issue?

Comment: http://imgur.com/VdLKiCZ

Comment: does there is any error in browser console?

Comment: No errors in browser console

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$timeout`:

```
$http.get('memoriesList1.json').success(function(data) {
  $timeout(function(){
      $scope.memories = data;
   })
});
```

When the view isn't updated, it's often caused by asynchronous calls.

In order to be sure that the view is updated, you have or to force a digesting cycle (`$scope.$apply()`) or, the preferred option, which is `$timeout`, which assure you that after the execution of the code within it, a digesting cycle will be executed

Comment: I did as you told me: .controller('View5Ctrl', ['$scope','$http','$timeout',function($scope, $http,$timeout) {
  $http.get('json/memoriesList1.json').success(function(data) {
     $timeout(function(){
      $scope.memories = data;
   })
   });
  }]); Problem still persists